# new lines in PHP. how?

Tags: php, newline

Code:

```
<?php

echo "Hello World!\nSecond line";

?>
```

I'm trying to display this as two separate lines but the line break character doesn't work and instead a space gets printed inbetween the two. I've tried \r\n as well as .PHP_EOL. as well as placing the string in single quotes. None of them seems to work. So how do I print new lines in PHP?

I'm working on phpDesigner 8

Comment: You need to be more specific about your use case here. Are you printing to the web browser or a console?

Comment: The problem is that the browser is interpreting the output of your script as HTML (since it was sent with `Content-Type: text/html` by default). HTML doesn't display EOL characters per se (ignoring <pre>, CSS, etc.).

Comment: Yup, if you want to break lines in HTML, use either a `<p>` tag for a new paragraph or a `<br />` tag, to create a linebreak. This has nothing to do with PHP.

Comment: As a side note, the \n is used a line break for texts in javascript alert/confirm boxes and alt/title attributes . Although these are normally only for accessibility/SEO pupose, I sometimes use the way browsers display it as a cheap "tooltip box"...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) to turn the new lines into HTML `<br/>` elements:

```
<?php

echo nl2br("Hello World!\nSecond line");

?>
```

Comment: Specifically, the `\n` *does* print newlines in PHP. HTML just doesn't care about them. They'll show up in "View Source", though.

Comment: Alternatively: set the correct HTTP headers so your browser known its rendering TEXT and not HTML: header('Content-type: text/plain');

Comment: @smassey: I answered something similar below. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20148999/1438393). :)

Answer (score 3):

The linebreaks are actually created but you just don't see them. Change the `Content-Type` header to see the original result:

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
```

This is very useful when debugging. You could also view the page source in your browser to see the original output.

And to answer your question, the most easiest way to do this would be to use [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/nl2br) (as has been suggested in John's answer above).

Comment: Beat me to it, seconds ahead ;)

Answer (score 0):

As you are printing in HTML, you should use the `<br />` tag instead of `\n`